# How to remove a line with a quote

Tags: parsing, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a bunch of logs that I what to process with logstash. Between each entry, there is this annoying line with just a double quote, that my pattern can't parse and results in a grokparsefailure. What's the best way of ignoring/removing it?

My input is

```
2016-09-18 00:00:02,013 UTC, idf="639b26a731284b43beac8b26f829bcab", message="24308 * thread http-nio-8443-exec-4
24308 > host: localhost:8443
24308 > user-agent: curl/7.40.0
" 
2016-09-18 00:02:35,555 UTC, idf="7d65da6966ec4c26a685b04ec7bfd851", message="24309 * thread http-nio-8443-exec-1
24309 > host: example.com
24309 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)
24309 > x-forwarded-for: 69.162.124.236
" 
2016-09-18 00:07:35,591 UTC, idf="8998b9c5f2de414182ce3143b4ec39af", message="24310 * thread http-nio-8443-exec-10
24310 > HEAD https://example.com/status
```

I've tried adding another grok filter at the beginning and then removing the field

```
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<onlyquote>\" )"}
    remove_field => [ "onlyquote" ]
  }
```

And gsub

```
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "message" , "\" \n" , "" ]
  }
```

But both approaches result in even more failures. Any idea?

Comment: Are your events multiline?

Comment: @Fairy Yes, I join lines starting with [\d]+, but not the ones with the quote.

Comment: I tested replacing `\n` myself and it seems they don't get picked up at all. Seems like escaping is broken?

Comment: You should just try to remove the quote with mutate/gsub: `gsub => [ "message" , "\"" , "" ]`. Or add the (escaped) quote at the beginning of your grok pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [drop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) filter:

```
if (/^"$/) { // match line contains only "
  drop {}
}
```

And put it before your `grok` filter